# Plasma on Arch theme problems

Tags: arch-linux, kde, plasma5, amd

When I try different themes in kde plasma, none of the transparent themes are actually transparent. Not getting any error messages. Wondering if anyone has had a similar problem.
Using amd ryzen 9 3900x cpu and amd 5700xt gpu.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know transparency effect is controlled by the user; not by the theme.
If setting the transparency does not work, install a compositing manager separately and you can either start it manually at startup by typing in a command or automatically start it. I recommend the **picom** compositing manager. You can find more details [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Picom) at arch wiki.